# PSD mockup template not getting design in place

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mockup

I am trying to create mockup for my business card design but when I paste the design in the smart object layer and save it, the design only gets the effect of the template but the design do not go into the place it should go. It appears as simple rectangle with the effects.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I tried 2 - 3 different template but getting same problem. Please help me guys

*This is how the mockup should look*
[image: How it should look]

*This is the result I get when I edit the Smart Object layer with my design*
[image: This is the result I get when I edit the Smart Object layer with my design]

Comment: So, what you are saying is that you do not know how to skew it to fit the "stack" in the background?

Comment: To be honest I am not well experienced with PS. I work mostly on Illustrator. I know about the skew in PS but really haven' t used it till now. Also I thought the template was supposed to do the skewing by itself

Comment: Perhaps a screencap of the layers in the unedited template would be helpful. It is also unclear to me if "paste my design into smart object" means you are making a new smart object or editing an existing one, and if editing, is that smart object skewed when editing it?

Answer (score 3):

Don't past the design into the document, 
edit the smart object of the original business card, 
this will open the smart object in new window,
paste your design into that.
Save and the original document will update with your smart object you just saved.

This video breaks it down
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKBNMTHVkcY

Comment: I am doing that only. I am right clicking the smart object layer and then click edit the content option and then change the design in that

Comment: does it also happen with this template?
http://www.iceflowstudios.com/2013/freebies/business-card-display-psd-template/

Comment: Tried this one too. But still no luck :/

Comment: ok it worked for me, what version of photoshop are you using? If the Transform was created in a later version of photoshop and you are using an older one, it can lose that the shape.

I tested this in CS6

Answer (score 0):

Well, There is actually a smart object square box at the bottom of later like an arrow. You need to double click on it and place your image by selecting from files > place image and you will get the result by pressing ctrl+S from keyboard and you are done! for example you may try this [template](http://www.graphicspsd.com/2016/01/leather-fabric-free-logo-mockup-psd.html) and see what I mean.

You are currently placing the image which will obviously not going to add any effect on mockup. You need to select the smart object square box with an arrow in it and place your image.